# I'm facing issue with importing bulk data from CSV file to neo4j desktop. i increased the memory heap to 8G but not able to import the data

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases, neo4j-desktop

ERROR: There is not enough memory to perform the current task. Please try increasing 'dbms.memory.heap.max_size' in the neo4j configuration (normally in 'conf/neo4j.conf' or, if you you are using Neo4j Desktop, found through the user interface) or if you are running an embedded installation increase the heap by using '-Xmx' command line flag, and then restart the database.

Comment: @Michael Hunger

Comment: Can you post sample code that's failing?

Comment: How much data are you trying to ingest?

Comment: @Pablissimo it is a CSV file, to whom i'm trying to load and make relationships but when i do this it shows this error. i updated my config file to memory : 8G that is maximum of my RAM size.

Comment: @djhallx it's 200000 records in my CSV file , these are all calls records.